# WPF - Closing window using MVVF command that runs new thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

**The setup**

I have a window and a viewmodel. The viewmodel has a command which executes a `Task`. When the task completes, I want the effect to be that the window closes.

What is the most acceptable (best-practice) way of doing this?

I tend to think that Dispatcher.Invoke is hacky and bad, but this is a moot point becaues the viewmodel does not have a reference to the window, or to its dispatcher.

edit: To clarify, the window belongs to the UI thread. The command itself calls a wrapper for doing an async http request (which returns a task). The command can append a ContinueWith.

I don't want to tightly couple the viewmodel to the view (such as by passing the Window to view model)

```
public class Api 
{
    Task MakeHttpCall();
}

public class ViewModel, DependencyObject
{
    private Api _api;

    public Task DoHttpCall() { return _api.MakeHttpCall(); }
    public MyCommand MyCommandInst { get; private set; }
}

public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    void Execute(object parameter)
    {
       var viewModel = GetViewModel(parameter);
       viewModel.DoHttpCall().ContinueWith( t => HandleCompletionAndSomehowTriggerWindowClose(t));
    }
}
```

And then the view.xaml:
    `<Button Command={Binding MyCommandInst} CommandParameter={Binding}>Do Stuff</Button>`

Comment: It's an old school thinking that using `Dispatcher.Invoke` is hacky and bad. There's a lot of use cases why `Dispatcher` is exposed in the first place. Can you show me the task creates the window? Show some code.

Comment: What about `task.ContinueWith`?

Comment: @lll using `Dispatcher.Invoke` is probably on the same level as referencing your view from your viewmodel. You certainly *could* do it. The MVVM police probably aren't going to like it, but who cares what they think.

Comment: @mikez `MVVM` is just a design pattern to follow. It is just a guide and sometimes you can't achieve pure `MVVM` and sometimes it's much easier to break the rules rather than getting yourself unstuck and is more readable to others than creating layers and layers just to achieve MVVM.

Comment: edited: see details. This is partial code, so class names are made up and irrelevant methods are left out.

@mikez: Maybe. What I'm doing is partially an academic exercise, so I want to figure out how to do this in a strictly MVVM sense.

re: dispatcher invoke... I'm not even clear on how it would work here (Dispatcher.Invoke)

Comment: If your ViewModel derives from `DependencyObject` then you're tightly tied to WPF. No reason not to reference UI elements and call methods on them directly. Of course that's really far from MVVM, or the proper way to do stuff in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I use MVVM Light to help facilitate this process. The ViewModel has no reference to the View it just publishes a message to close and the View is registered to receive those messages.

In the code behind of my view, I subscribe to the Messenger service like this:

```
public class MyView
{
   public MyView()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, msg =>
      {
         if ((msg.Sender == this.DataContext) && (msg.Notification.ToUpper() == "CLOSE"))
            this.Close();
      });
   }
}
```

Then in the ViewModel (either in the callback method from your async process or at the end of the command method if not running async):

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage(this, "Close"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I believe, closing a window with the MVVM pattern depends on raising some form of `Close` event on the view-model that the view subscribes to:

```
public class MyView
{
    public MyView(MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        viewModel.Close += (_, __) => Dispatcher.Invoke(this.Close);
    }
}
```

Raise the `Close` event from your task's `ContinueWith` action, and you're done.